# Adding a value to a hidden text box

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an image id value to a hidden text box whenever `drawX` is executed and and make it null when `clear` is executed. The way my program should work is that it should only draw an x on one image at a time. So whenever that image is selected it will send that image's id to the hidden text box that I named with an id of `sendServ` . The way I have it written right now, I don't think id is being passed to my `drawX` function in my `OptionClick` function. I'm not exactly sure how to get it to work. Maybe there is a simpler way by just using EventListener but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit: I decided to add a snippet with a dummy array so it might be easier to help me.

```js
let index = 0;
var hdnName = document.getElementById("sendServ");
const display = "table"; // or "grid" if horizontal, but this migh depend where you place the rest of the code, cause i added the style to the body
const x = 0;
const y = 0;
const images = {
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  url: [
    "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F8%2F84%2FAssociation_of_Gay_and_Lesbian_Psychiatrists_logo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
    "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic01.nyt.com%2Fnewsgraphics%2F2016%2F07%2F14%2Fpluto-one-year%2Fassets%2Ficon-pluto.png&f=1&nofb=1",
    "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.oFxADNN67dYP-ke5xg7HbQHaHG%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
    "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glassdoor.com%2Fsqll%2F1065746%2Felevation-church-squarelogo-1453223965790.png&f=1&nofb=1"
  ],
  id: [0, 1, 2, 3]
};

function createHTML() {
  console.log("E: Execute & R: Request & I: Informative");
  //loop to go true all images
  document.body.style.display = display;
  for (const image of images.url) {
    //each image will correspond to a canvas element
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //each canvas element will has is own properties (in this case all the same)
    canvas.id = "option" + [index];
    canvas.height = images.height;
    canvas.width = images.width;
    canvas.style.padding = "10px";

    //function to get the corresponded image of that particular canvas element
    drawImages(canvas);

    //add an event listener for when a user click on the particular canvas
    canvas.addEventListener("click", optionClick, false);

    //all html part was handle we can append it to the body
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    index++;
  }
}

function drawImages(canvas) {
  //we need to use the getContext canvas function to draw anything inside the canvas element
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const background = new Image();

  //This is needed because if the drawImage is called from a different place that the createHTML function
  //index value will not be at 0 and it will for sure with an heigher id that the one expected
  //so we are using regex to remove all letters from the canvas.id and get the number to use it later
  index = canvas.id.replace(/\D/g, "");

  //console.log('E: Drawing image ' + index + ' on canvas ' + canvas.id);

  //get the image url using the index to get the corresponded image
  background.src = images.url[index];
  //no idea why but to place the image, we need to use the onload event
  //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage
  background.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  };
}

function drawX(canvas, item) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 // console.log("E: Placing X on canvas " + canvas.id);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(images.width, images.height);
  ctx.moveTo(images.height, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, images.width);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  hdnName.value = item;
}

function clear(canvas) {
  //console.log("E: clearing canvas " + canvas.id);

  canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  drawImages(canvas);
   hdnName.value = null;
}

function optionClick(e) {
  log = true;
  var index = 0;
  const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");

  for (const option of canvas) {
    if (log)
      console.log("I: User clicked at option " + e.target.id + ":" + option.id);
    log = false;
    if (e.target.id === option.id) {
      // console.log('R: Drawing request at canvas ' + option.id);
      var item = images.id[index];
      console.log(item);
      drawX(option, item);
    } else {
      //  console.log('R: Clearing request at canvas ' + option.id);
      clear(option);
    }
    index++;
  }
}

//We start by calling createHTML (that will handle with all HTML elements)
window.onload = createHTML;
```

```css
canvas.suiteiCanvas {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;

  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 150px;

  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
}

#draw-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 16px 3px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

img.new {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;

  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 150px;

  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);

}
```

```html
<body></body>
<input type="text" id="sendServ">
```

Comment: _“I don't think id is being passed to my drawX function in my OptionClick function.”_ - and what exactly makes you think that? All you have to do it log the value of the `item` parameter to console inside of `drawX`, to see that you’re wrong here - it does get passed fine. And as soon as you un-comment `// hdnName.value = item;`, the values from 0 to 3 start appearing in the text field, when the images get clicked … if that is not what you wanted, then I don’t get what you’re asking here.

Comment: Nevermind, I see my problem. I was adding making hdnName.value = null; when I was clearing it so it would drawX and then clear it and make the value null.